# Split an uneven number in even shares

Tags: c#, math

Hi I'd like to know how I could split a number for example 2000 in 6 parcels but, in a way that all numbers are whole like:
 334,00 334,00 333,00 333,00 333,00 333,00
 or
 335,00 333,00 333,00 333,00 333,00 333,00

Comment: What have you tried to do so far to solve this problem?  What issues are you having with your attempted solutions?

Comment: That's extremely vague. For example, you could just use five `1`'s and `N-5`

Comment: @Jonesy or just five zeros and N.

Comment: All I could think off was the regular divide the number by 6 witch I though would be a pretty useless code. I don't even know what would be add five 1's and N-5. I don't have much knowledge in math yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Divide number by 6 and round to the nearest number.
2. Your first 5 numbers were calculated in step 1.
3. Last number = Initial number - (5 x number from step 1)

Answer (score 1):

You could just do an algorythm that removed the decimals from the parcels, then add them all and add the result to your first one until no decimals are left.

Comment: `-1` sounds like a comment to me and not an answer especially since what you have written has no coded examples to support what the `OP` is looking for

Comment: Taking in account that this website isn't for asking for code to do stuff, i think it's a fair answer.

Comment: Should be a comment what you have stated gives the OP very little direction look at the Answer above and you will see that it's easier even with a written step by step what to do or try vs what you have written

Comment: I tried your solution and it works. I divided 2000/6 = 6x333,333... and did 5x333 = 1665 and 2000 - 1665 = 335 so It became 1x335 and 5x 333.